# H2O2 + NaCl + H(+) reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

So I found these reduction potentials online:

$$\begin{alignat}{2}
\ce{H2O2 + 2H+ + 2e- \;&<=> 2H2O}\qquad &&E=1.78\ \mathrm V\\
\ce{2Cl- \;&<=> Cl2 + 2e-}\qquad &&E=-1.36\ \mathrm V
\end{alignat}$$

If the net reduction potential is positive will chlorine gas be spontaneously formed when salt and hydrogen peroxide are mixed in a acidic solution?

Comment: Exactly what is an acidic base...? Anyway, theoretically, yes. However kinetically the reaction may not be favoured.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  If you get the pH right and the stoichiometry absolutetly 1:1 then you might form $\ce{Cl2}$.  However your reaction will compete with other reaction and you will more likely oxidize the chlorine into chlorate ions ($\ce{ClO-}$, $\ce{ ClO2-}$, $\ce{ClO3-}$, or $\ce{ClO4-}$).

Comment: If you want to form chlorine I suggest calcium hypochlorite and hydrochloric acid or potassium permanganate and hydrochloric acid.